# Mysql Query without Repeat!

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I will Explain what i want...

I have a table with records like this

...........................

**country_name - username**

India - abc1

Australia - abc2

India - abc3

USA - abc4

Australis - abc5

Lebanon - abc6

...........................

From Above Table I need to get country list without repeat, is there any chance to get like this...

**Ex Code:**

```
$sql = 'bla bla bla bla bla';

$res = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo $row['country_name'].'<br /><br />';
}
```

**Ex Output(Like this):**

India

Australia

USA

Lebanon

If is there any change to solve my issue please tell me and advance thanks for that!

Comment: are `country_name` and `user_name` separate columns?  If so try `SELECT DISTINCT country_name FROM ...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use DISTINCT:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT country_name FROM table";
```

Answer (score 9):

Change your code to this -

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct country_name from my_table";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo $row['country_name'].'<br /><br />';
}
```

From this [link](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL) -

> DISTINCT helps to eliminate duplicates.  If a query returns a result that contains duplicate rows, you can remove duplicates to produce a result set in which every row is unique. To do this, include the keyword DISTINCT after SELECT and before the output column list.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT country_name FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(country_name) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `country_name` FROM `table_name`
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
SELECT [ FIELDS ] FROM [ TABLE NAME  ] WHERE ....... GROUP BY country_name
```